# How to start a Spark master standalone programmatically in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do you start a Spark master standalone programmatically in Scala?

Related to this doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html
How do we achieve the equivalent of `./sbin/start-master.sh` in Scala?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following lines of code:

import sys.process._

"./sbin/start-master.sh".!

Make sure that the command ./sbin/start-master.sh path is correct, else you will get error=2, No such file or directory.

Else, give the full path for the command.